# Problem with condition in a table by using counters

Tags: tables, conditionals, counters

I'm trying to make a conditional dynamic table that uses counter for comparison but i got a irrational error, Please see the following code:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[hidelinks]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcounter{generalCounter}
\begin{document}
\def\anyy{a}
\begin{longtable}{cccc}
  \setcounter{generalCounter}{0}\foreach\element in\anyy{\stepcounter{generalCounter}}
  \ifnum\thegeneralCounter=1
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
  \fi
  \ifnum\thegeneralCounter=2
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
  \fi
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

This code works fine, but if i change `\def\anyy{a}` to `\def\anyy{a,b}`, can not build and showen error is `! Incomplete \ifnum; all text was ignored after line 11.`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer :  Thank you so much christian, sorry I don't have permission for upvote.

Comment: You can come back at any time and if you have more reputation, you can upvote answers and other questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The looping with `\foreach` isn't the issue, but `\anyy` isn't getting expanded correctly. In addition, the test `\ifnum` begins in one tabular cell and ends in other ones -- this is weird and can be catched only with tricks, i.e. black TeX magic ;-)

A simpler way is to use `\prg_replicate:nn` here, a, `expl3` macro, that performs expandable loops and survives the grouping involved with tabular cells.

The helper macro `\generatelines` stores the argument in a `\clist` and counts its elements with `\clist_count:N`, which is the number of repetitions to be made.

The actual tabular line entry is another, 'freely' configurable helper macro, e.g. `\modeltableentry`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\modeltableentry}{%
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \tabularnewline \hline
}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\generatelines}{+m}{%
  \clist_set:Nx \l_tmpa_clist {#1}
  \prg_replicate:nn {\clist_count:N \l_tmpa_clist } {\modeltableentry}
}
 \ExplSyntaxOff 
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\anyy}{a,b}
\begin{longtable}{cccc}
  \generatelines{\anyy}
\end{longtable}


\renewcommand{\anyy}{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k}

\begin{longtable}{cccc}
  \generatelines{\anyy}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```